# Select max value for which condition x is fulfilled in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a flexible attribution model for site traffic. I've started out by making a last-click model, where a conversion is attributed to a channel of traffic based on the last visit a visitor made prior to converting. So:

```
Visitor     Visit      Channel  ConversionId
visitor a   visit 1    email    123
visitor a   visit 2    email    123
visitor a   visit 3    direct   123
visitor b   visit 1    seo      123
visitor b   visit 2    direct   123
visitor b   visit 3    email    123
visitor c   visit 1    seo      123
visitor c   visit 2    direct   123
visitor c   visit 3    direct   123
```

In the above example, I would count each visitor's final visit and attribute the conversion to that channel. So, visitor a and visitor c's conversions would be attributed to direct, while visitor b's would be attributed to email.

Now I want to be able to exclude direct, and thus be able to attribute the conversion to the last non-direct channel. In this scenario, visitor a and visitor b's conversions would be attributed to email (visitor a's 3rd visit would be excluded), while visitor c's conversion would be attributed to se (as c's second and third visits would be excluded).

The way I have this set up so far is (and some of this looks a little goofy because I stripped some joins and identifying info out for simplicity):

```
WITH test (visitor,
           visit, --a number unique for each visitor row but not necessarily unique across all visits
           channel,
           conversionid,
           rn) AS
(
SELECT visitorid AS visitor,
       visitid AS visit,
       channel AS channel,
       conversionid AS conversionid
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY conversionid ORDER BY visit DESC)
FROM db
GROUP BY visitorid,
         visitid,
         channel,
         conversionid)

SELECT visitor,
       MAX(visit) AS maxvisit,
     channel,
     conversionid
FROM test
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY visitor,
         channel
ORDER BY visitor;
```

This gives me last-click attribution. (There was an easier way for me to do this but that way didn't look as flexible--I want to be able to easily change the query to exclude channels.) My question is, what do I do so I can exclude direct and attribute the conversion to the last non-direct channel? I'd also like to be able to exclude additional channels if needed so I can build different attribution models.

Thanks a million, guys.

Comment: what if direct is the only channel for a user do you want to exclude that user all together?

Comment: plus I have looked at your code and your example data and there just isn't much alighnment.  I might suggest giving us an example as it relates more directly to your code and then presenting us with your desired output.  For example MAX(visit) just seems to get the Last VisitId regardless of channel.  And row number does as well.... So do you want MAX(VisitId) and then Channel of MAX(VisitId) that is not direct or simply MAX(VisitId that is not direct) and channel of that id?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't simply add "WHERE channel <> 'direct'"?

Comment: @Matt re: your first comment, it would be best to know that the visitor is excluded so I can compare the total number of visitors between last-click and last non-direct click to ensure that the query isn't filtering anything important. As to your second, you're right, I've fixed the original code. In trying to anonymize the code I got a bit lost in the weeds. So I added some relevant data. As for the ambiguity you point out in the code, sorry, I'm quite new to SQL so was a bit unclear. I want MAX(visitid) for each visitor where the channel associated with that visitid is not direct.

Comment: @rd_nielsen yeah, I thought about that but that seems to exclude all records where direct is the final channel. For example, I have 272k records of last clicks in the db, but when I include the suggested line of code I get 221k records, and it's basically impossible that 50k records would consist solely of direct visits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you want so here are some statistics examples that hopefully will make this a little easier for you to understand.  This section is geared toward Conditional Aggregation which allows you to Mix and Match such as take the `MAX` `VisitId` regardless of `conversion` that is associated and get the last channel that isn't direct.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (visitor CHAR(1), VisitId INT, ConversionId INT, Channel VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES  ('a',1, 11,'email'),('a',2, 12,'email'),('a',3, 13,'direct')
,('b',4, 14,'seo'),('b',5, 15,'direct'),('b',6, 16,'email'),('c',7, 17,'seo')
,('c',8, 18,'direct'),('c',9, 19,'direct')

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
           visitor
           ,VisitId
           ,Channel
           ,ConversionId
           ,DirectConversion = CASE WHEN Channel = 'direct' THEN ConversionId END
           ,ChannelRowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY visitor
              ORDER BY
                 CASE WHEN Channel = 'direct' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 ,ConversionId DESC)

        FROM
           @Table
    )

    SELECT
        visitor
        ,MaxVisitId = MAX(VisitId)
        ,MaxVisitIdOfNonDirect = MAX(CASE WHEN DirectConversion IS NULL THEN VisitId END)
        ,NumOfVisits = COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId)
        ,Channel = MAX(CASE WHEN ChannelRowNumber = 1 THEN Channel END)
        ,NumOfConversions = COUNT(DISTINCT ConversionId)
        ,NumOfDirectConversions = COUNT(DISTINCT DirectConversion)
        ,NumOfNonDirectConversions = COUNT(DISTINCT ConversionId) - COUNT(DISTINCT DirectConversion)
    FROM
        cte
    GROUP BY
        visitor
```

If you just want to rule out Channel all together then using ROW_NUMBER and WHERE <> 'direct' should do the trick for you.

Comment: Oh man I think this does it!! I'll need some more time to validate as I've been on this for far too long today and need a break but I think you nailed it.

Can you explain to me how this works? Would googling "conditional aggregation" lay it out for me?

Comment: @mowshowitz yeah googling it will probably lay it out well for you but the idea is you create the case expression or iif inside the aggregate function so that the case will have nulls for what you don't want to count, sum, max etc. So that when the aggregation is applied it is only calculating the values you want. So in this case you filter out the direct values and only aggregate the others.

Comment: Hey @Matt so I was able to validate the results of the query today and it appears that it's doing SOMETHING but not quite what I'm looking for. The counts of conversions attributed to each channel has definitely changed, and the overall pool has shrunken about 3%, but there are still a lot of conversions attributed to direct.

To clarify, if the clickpath contains a direct click that is not the last click, that's fine. I only want conversions whose LAST click is attributed to direct to be instead attributed to the first non-direct click immediately prior.

Comment: consider the clickpaths:

`seo > direct > seo > seo > direct > email` (would be attributed to email)

`direct > direct > seo > email > seo` (would be attributed to seo)

`email > seo > direct > direct`  (would be attributed to seo)

`direct > seo > email > direct` (would be attributed to email)

`direct > direct > direct > direct > direct` (would be NULL)

Does that make sense? Last non-direct click would get the conversion attributed to it.

Comment: @mowshowitz I am not following your comments here I was attempting to show you some techniques to find what you want but what you want is not totally clear to me.  If you could put example data and desired result in your question I and others will be able to answer more appropriately

Comment: No worries, I was able to finally figure it out this week, but your input was invaluable. I really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way:

```
SELECT db.*
FROM (SELECT db.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY conversionid
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN channel <> 'Direct' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
                                         visit DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM db
     ) db
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This will return the most recent record for each `conversionid` that is not `Direct`, if there is one.

Comment: Seems like malicious, multiple, anonymous downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server the below code is worth trying

```
select visitor,channel,conversionid,
dense_rank() over(partition by visitor order by visit desc) as rn
into #visitor
from visitor
where channel <> 'Direct'
order by visitor,visit 

select v1.visitor,count(v2.visit) as visits ,v1.channel,v1.conversionid 
from #visitor v1 join visitor v2
on v1.visitor=v2.visitor and  v1.rn=1
group by v1.visitor,v1.channel,v1.conversionid
```